# How do I improve my Netflix quality on Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, netflix

Hello I used to use Ubuntu a bunch a while ago and have recently transitioned back to the operating system, I've noticed that now Netflix only seems to show all their content in 540p with a low bitrate on Ubuntu on both Firefox and Chrome (I used the Ctrl+Alt+Shift+D command to check). So I was wondering if there is any way I can improve the quality I'm receiving, its quite ugly to watch to be honest. Thank you!

Comment: I've never used netflix but I thought the more you pay the better the bandwidth? Also I wonder if the country you are in is a factor.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm currently paying for the HD plan, if I jump on over to my Windows install I can watch in HD no problems.

Comment: What does the Ctrl + Alt  + Shift + D command do? I'm trying to verify the bitrate on my system.

Comment: @Jos Ok so while you're in the middle of watching a Movie or TV series on Netflix if you use the Ctrl + Alt + Shift + D Command it'll bring up some text displaying resolution, bit rate and such of the video you're currently watching

Comment: The key combination apparently doesn't work on my system. The video looks pretty sharp though, not blurry at all, no pixelation occurs. Screen width is 1752 pixels.

Comment: @rykez I use netflix without issue. since you're using a webapp there won't be any difference between windows and ubuntu. I would advise you stick to chrome though. and keep away from chromium. it does not support netflix.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Netflix's help](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742) we are stuck with 720p on Linux.

You could try a Windows virtual machine (or even Chrome OS?).

Some web browser extensions are supposed to avoid that limitation, but I have never tried them.

Comment: The link is to Netflix but doesn't contain the word Linux anywhere on the page.

Comment: HTML5 section: "Google Chrome: Up to 720p on Windows, Mac, and Linux" and "Mozilla Firefox up to 720p". And the other browsers are... non-friendly to Linux.

Comment: The OP said 540p so your non-answer is irrelevant.